# Find number of ranges (a[i], a[i+1]) which contains the value k for i in range a, b

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

Given an array of n elements, how do I find the number of ranges [min(A[i], A[i+1]), max(A[i], A[i+1])] which contains a given value k. Here i lies between 0 <= a < b < n for zero-based indexing, where a and b are zero-based indexes.

For example, for the below array with a = 1, and b = 3;

6 3 2 8 5

Suppose for k = 3, it has to be found in range [min(A[1], A[2]), max(A[1], A[2])] and [min(A[2], A[3]), max(A[2], A[3])]. Here k=3 appears in both the ranges [2, 3] and [2, 8] so the answer is 2.

How could I find the count of ranges in less than linear time with certain pre-computation?

I don't need the exact code, just a high level overview of the approach/data structure would do.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *Here i lies between a < b < n* Isn't `0 <= i <= n-1` ? What are `a` and `b`?

Comment: I don't understand `i lies between a < b < n` -- `a` is an array, not an integer. And `b` is unknown?

Comment: Sorry A is the array, updating the question

Comment: Still, what is a and b?

Comment: Search for "how do I iterate through an array c++" and "how do I compare two elements c++" and "how do I compare one element to two other elements c++"

Comment: `
int ctr = 0;
for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
{
if ( A[i]<k && A[i+1]> k)
  ctr++;
}
printf(" Count: %i", ctr);
`
I dont get the question, why doesn't this work?

Comment: @JacobN it will work, but I require something faster than that. Similar queries will appear quite often so some precomputation can be done

Comment: do you have a brute force implementation? If I would try to solve it I would always start with the most simple, because while implementing it some opportunities for a better algorithm may become obvious. If not, why do you think there is a sublinear algorithm? Also, do you really need it? For relatively small input sizes often a simple algorithm performs better than a complicated one, even if asymptotic complexity would suggest something else

Comment: btw your `a` and `b` are still rather confusing. If you consider only part of the array (from `A[a] == A[1]` till `A[b] == A[3]`) then forget about the rest and write an algorithm that considers the full array

Comment: @idclev463035818 Here, n <= 10^5. A linear time algo will be just to traverse the array in the range [a, b] and count the number of occurrences where the value k lies in between the consecutive elements. But for multiple queries say q <= 10^5, this approach would time out

Comment: what means "would time out" ? Is this for a online coding contest? tbh I suddenly lost some of my interest in the question

Answer (score 0):

You can save some time by previously kicking out all elements *i* of the array *A* which fullfill `(A[i-1] <= A[i] and A[i] <= A[i+1]) or ((A[i-1] >= A[i] and A[i] >= A[i+1])`. Then counting the valid interval range number should still be the same.

```
int ctr = 0; 
for(i=a;i<b-1;i++) 
{ 
  if ( (A[i]<=k && A[i+1]>= k) ||  (A[i]>=k && A[i+1]<= k) ) 
    ctr++; 
} 
printf(" Count: %i", ctr);
```